# Network Reachability is not working iOS 7.0.3

Tags: ios, ios7

I am new to stackoverflow. we are using DDG(Donoho Design Group) Reachability API http://blog.ddg.com/?p=24.
Till iOS6, iOS7 GM seed, iOS7.0.1, 7.0.2 it is working fine, but with iOS7.0.3 it was delayed by more than 3 mins. Our App is suffering with this behaviour.

Has anybody facing this issue in 7.0.3? It would great help if anybody found the solution

Thanks,
Purushotham Jinka

Comment: DDG Reachability API is nearly 3 years old now. It was built to improve on Reachability 2.0 from Apple. I would recommend using Apple Reachability as it is now in version 3.0 which was released back in August

Comment: I have tried to use new version 3.0, i am still facing the problem.

My scenario is iPad device is connected to wifi router, when app is in foreground state disconnect the WAN cable for router, now reachability is not detecting internet status change. Same problem with while connecting the WAN cable also. It is almost taking 5 min to get new status. I have observed this problem even with Safari, Appstore apps also. I think this is iOS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using AFNetworking Reachability. It worked for me. Even I was facing the same problem.

Apple's Reachability is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this:

In your declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic) Reachability *reachability;
```

Implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [self.reachability startNotifier];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleNetworkChange:)
                                                 name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                              object:nil];
}

- (void)handleNetworkChange:(NSNotification *)notice {

   NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [self.reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable)
    {

    }
    else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFi)
    {

    }
    else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWWAN)
    {

    }
}
```